# Android gallery nextfocus not working

Tags: android, focus, gallery

I am using gallery as below

```
   <Gallery android:nextFocusUp="@+id/zoom_out"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icon_gallery_plate" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:spacing="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/browse_slider_bar"
    android:unselectedAlpha="0.5" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layoutZoom" 
    />
```

Problem is as i defined nextFocusup zoom out when i press up key while on the gallery it don't focus to zoom out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution add nextfocusup id in adatper's getview method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /* calculationg position */
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        BrowseMapCategoryRow catRow = getItem(position);
        /* Replacing with selected image */
        i.setImageResource(catRow.getImageSource());
        i.setNextFocusUpId(R.id.zoom_out); // setting manullay
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In "nextFocusUp" you should put an id that already exists, the + adds a new id: so when you create the widget that will gain the focus, you should eliminate the +, so the id would be android:id="@id/zoom_out"